# Jenkins Build Git Revision Missing?

Tags: jenkins

Has anyone else noticed for each build that used Git, Jenkins would list a git revision hash which was a long alphanumeric string to uniquely identify in git the code revision it was built from is now missing?

It is still listed in the build.xml under the xml tag  for that build but is not displayed on the build page.

It says the branch path still but the revision string is missing. Bug or something else? Thanks!

Comment: The long alphanumeric string is the commit hash. A tag is different thing, which can be made manually (eg: v1.2). A single commit may have multiple tags, but only one commit hash.

Comment: Sorry for the term mixup. I do mean the hash is missing and not displayed on the build output screen.